# How to make dictionary from list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have this variables:

```
fab_centrum = ['A', 'B'] 
sales_line = ['1AA', '2BB', '3CC', '1AA', '2BB', '3CC']
keys = ['feasibility_score', 'capacity_score']
feasibility_score = [10,30,40, 10,30,40]
capacity_score = [50,60,70, 50,60,70]
```

And I would like to make dic with this structure

```
    bach = {
                A: {'1AA': {
                  feasibility_score: 10,
                  capacity_score: 50,
                  }
                  '2BB': {
                  feasibility_score: 10,
                  capacity_score: 50,
                  }
                   }
                  
           B: {'1AA': {
                  feasibility_score: 10,
                  capacity_score: 50,
                  }
....
                }
    
    
    }
```

I know I can use something like

```
batch = dict.fromkeys(fab_centrum, sales_line)
```

But I dont know how to make dict with nested values like my structue.
I am new to python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the result below what you want instead?

It looks strange that `sales_line`, `feasibility_score`, and `capacity_score` have duplicate elements inside...but feel free to add them back as long as they have the same length so that `zip()` won't cut some elements off.

More on the `collections` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections

More on the `zip()`function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

```
from collections import defaultdict

fab_centrum = ['A', 'B']
sales_line = ['1AA', '2BB', '3CC']
keys_ = ['feasibility_score', 'capacity_score']
feasibility_score = [10, 30, 40]
capacity_score = [50, 60, 70]

batch = defaultdict(dict)
for sl, fs, cs in zip(sales_line, feasibility_score, capacity_score):
    for char in fab_centrum:
        batch[char][sl] = {keys_[0]: fs, keys_[1]: cs}

print(batch)
```

#### Result:

```
{
'A': 
    {
    '1AA':{'feasibility_score': 10, 'capacity_score': 50}, 
    '2BB':{'feasibility_score': 30, 'capacity_score': 60}, 
    '3CC':{'feasibility_score': 40, 'capacity_score': 70}
    }, 

'B': 
    {
    '1AA': {'feasibility_score': 10, 'capacity_score': 50}, 
    '2BB': {'feasibility_score': 30, 'capacity_score': 60}, 
    '3CC': {'feasibility_score': 40, 'capacity_score': 70}
    }
}
```